# Issue with condition race issue with Loading Interceptor in Angular

Tags: angular

I am having a few issues with my loading interceptor and a presumed condition race that is causing this error: `Uncaught (in promise) overlay does not exist` to appear sometime within my loading interceptor/service.

Since my app uses numerous (1 to 5) http calls on some pages, I opted to create a interceptor that counted the http requests to present and dismiss the loading overlay. It looks something like this:

```
export class LoadingInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  private totalRequests = 0;

  constructor(private loading: LoadingService) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    this.totalRequests++;

    if (this.totalRequests === 1) {
      this.loading.present();
    }

    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        this.totalRequests--;
        if (this.totalRequests === 0) {
          this.loading.dismiss();
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

For my loading service, I tried to have the logic check for if the loader was present on the callback using a true/false flag, then either present or dismiss it.

```
isLoading = false;

  constructor(
    public loadingController: LoadingController
  ) { }

  async present() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    return await this.loadingController.create({
      spinner: "circular",
      translucent: true
    }).then(a => {
      a.present().then(() => {
        if (!this.isLoading) {
          a.dismiss().then(() => this.isLoading = false);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  async dismiss() {
    this.isLoading = false;
    return await this.loadingController.dismiss().then(() => this.isLoading = false);
  }
```

However, as I mentioned, everyone once in a while, I am still having the condition race issue where the error pops up. Anyone have any thoughts on what may be causing the issue?

Comment: There is no issue with loading interceptor. overlay does not exist - This error is occurring because loadingController.dismiss() is called before  loadingController gets a chance to completly build a circular loader.

Comment: Google for Loading Controller, dismiss() is called before present() or similar and your problem might solve.